# Runtime Error 13 when TextBox containing a Date is empty

Tags: excel, vba, string, date

Despite of checking many questions relating error 13, I could not find answers to my problem, so I am giving a shot here:

I am building my code to save information from a userform, but first I am testing to see if mandatory textboxes are empty. Since I am using a 64 bits machine I have used Trevor Eyre´s CalendarForm.

However while testing the code I hit a problem with the empty textboxes that receives the dates from CalendarForms:

In this line:

```
Dim dteCompraDataOps As Date: dteCompraDataOps = Me.txtTesouro_Compra_DataOps.value
```

This part is highlighted and returns Runtime Error 13:

```
dteCompraDataOps = Me.txtTesouro_Compra_DataOps.value
```

When I check the values coming from empty TextBoxes I get:

```
dteCompraDataOps = "00:00:00"`
```

Which is correct since it should be treated as Date, but this:

```
Me.txtTesouro_Compra_DataOps.value = ""
```

Is coming as a string.

I did a little search and noticed that Date data types are tricky when the textbox they come from are empty.

I could find a solution: creating a Select Case to test the mandatory fields before declaring the variables but I would like o learn how to deal with the empty textboxes that are supposed to be empty.

Any chance you can shed some light into my conundrum?

Thanks in advance.
Cub4_RJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this.

a) Check for Null:

```
With Me.txtTesouro_Compra_DataOps
    If Not IsNull(.Value) Then
        If IsDate(.Value) Then dteCompraDataOps = . Value
    End if
End With
```

b) Introduce a new variable of `Variant` type which accepts everything (including nulls) and check it's value.

```
Dim rawData As variant
rawData = Me.txtTesouro_Compra_DataOps.Value

If Not IsNull(rawData) Then
    If IsDate(rawData) Then dteCompraDataOps = rawData
End If
```

The problem with approach A, is that the value 123 is treated as a date, however option B will catch it.

Comment: Thanks for your response Kostas. Will both cases have to run before the variables are defined, correct? Reason for this question is because this error only appears when the variable is positioned before the SELECT CASE or IF that will catch eventual blank TextBoxes. Whenever I place the "blank catcher" after the variables being defined I get the error 13 - hence my question if I could define Dates in another way so VBA won´t try to debug it before runing the code.

Comment: Kostas, I have just revised your option 2 and applied to my code. It is indeed working as I expected. Thanks!